# Changing date format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a bunch of observations that are in `M/d/yyyy` format. I would like to create a separate attribute column where each observation is listed by year only. But I can't just select columns by year, as I tried to do by creating an expression in my screenshot.

Is there a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: What QGIS version?  What field type is observed_on?

Answer (score 8):

Use the field calculator to create a new field, then define the expression using the right() function to extract just the year from your "observed_on" field.

In this case you will need 4 characters.

```
right("observed_on", 4)
```

Answer (score 7):

First you need to convert your string ('mm-dd-yy') to a date (yyyy-MM-dd). Then you can extract the year with year() function.

All in one: `year(make_date(20||substr("obvserved_on",7,2),substr("obvserved_on",1,2),substr("obvserved_on",4,2)))`

*Note that you need to add 20 (or 19 or whatever) in front of your year (the `20||` part) since it is formatted with only two numbers instead of four.*

Edit: as I can see in your Screenshot, your Datestring is not formatted as `'mm-dd-yy'`, but actually `'M/d/yyyy'`. You can use regular expressions or arrays in that case. Like this: `year(make_date(array_get( string_to_array( "observed_on",'/'),2),array_get( string_to_array( "observed_on",'/'),0),array_get( string_to_array( "observed_on",'/'),1)))`

You can create a new field by opening your attribute table and executing field calculator. Enter your expression there. See:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and where do I enter this code?  Do I just plug it into the expression in the field calculator?

Comment: One can format the date directly: `year(to_date(obvserved_on,'M-d-yyyy'))`

Comment: @JGH true that. Seems like I was stuck in my brain on the year having only two numbers, which does not allow to directly format it (see my note). You should add this as another answer.

Comment: :-) `yy` should work.

Comment: @JGH this returns 1900 instead of 2000 by default.

Comment: hum.... maybe in Qt6 some dates will be considered as being in the current millennium..  https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74323

Answer (score 3):

Simplifying [@MrXsquared](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380213/84870)'s answer, one can directly format the recorded date:

`year(to_date(obvserved_on,'M/d/yyyy'))`

with the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdate.html#fromString-1) saying:

> **M** The month as a number without a leading zero (1 to 12)
> **d** The day
> as a number without a leading zero (1 to 31)
> **yyyy**  The year as a
> four digit number, possibly plus a leading minus sign for negative
> years.
> **All other** input characters will be treated as text.